# Pass values from plain-text to a method on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below code for login in using Ldap Authentication in ASP.net. However, I don't know how to pass the values from plain-text to this code. I want to run this through button click.

```
public class LdapAuthentication
{
    private string _path;
    private string _filterAttribute;
    public LdapAuthentication(string path)
    {
        _path = path;

    }
    public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd)
    {
        string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

        try
        {
            // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
            Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (null == result)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //if (result != null)
            //{
            //    string mail = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();

            //}

            // Update the new path to the user in the directory
            _path = result.Path;
            _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
            _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["mail"][0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }
    public string GetGroups()
    {
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
        search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
        search.Filter = "(mail=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
            String dn;
            //int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

            for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount;
                 propertyCounter++)
            {
                dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];

                //equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                //commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                //if (-1 == equalsIndex)
                //{
                //    return null;
                //}
                //groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1),
                //                  (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                //groupNames.Append("|");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. " +
              ex.Message);
        }
        return groupNames.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean you need a UI with several text boxes and a button which sends the text box data to IsAuthenticated? If so, what UI framework are you using (i.e. WPF, Winforms)?

Comment: I have two textboxs in this page (Id and password) however dont know how to pass these value to this function within this class. On button click. So it can authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an oversimplification but...

```
 public void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LdapAuthentication auth = new LdapAuthentication("YOURPATH");
    if (auth.IsAuthenticated("YOURDOMAIN", txtId.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
        //Login Passed
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you are using WebForms and your username textbox has the ID "txtId", and your password textbox has ID "txtPassword".

If you are not using WebForms the implementation will be different. As spectacularbob mentioned, we can't really answer your question until we know which UI Framework you are using.